# Get-SMBShare save that output to a CSV

Tags: powershell, smb

I want to export output to a CSV. But I can't export correctly.

```
foreach ($share in (Get-SmbShare)) {
    $share | Get-SmbShareAccess | % {
        $_ |
            Add-Member -Name 'Path' -Value $share.Path -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru |
            Select Name, Path, AccountName, AccessControlType, AccessRight
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the output from the `foreach(){...}` loop to a variable, then pipe that to `Export-Csv`:

```
$shareAccess = foreach ($share in (Get-SmbShare)) {
    $share | Get-SmbShareAccess | % {
        $_ |
            Add-Member -Name 'Path' -Value $share.Path -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru |
            Select Name, Path, AccountName, AccessControlType, AccessRight
    }
}

$shareAccess |Export-Csv .\path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi , I have a question. have you had a chance take a look this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150840/extracting-specific-lines-and-export-to-the-another-txt-file

Answer (score 0):

Something like that I think

```
 Get-SmbShare | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $share = $_
        return $share | Get-SmbShareAccess | 
            ForEach-Object {
                return [PSCustomObject]@{Share=$share; Access=$_}
            }
    } |
    ForEach-Object {
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.Share.Name
            Path = $_.Share.Path
            AccessName = $_.Access.AccountName
            AccessType = $_.Access.AccessControlType
            AccessRight = $_.Access.AccessRight
        }
    } |
    Out-GridView
```