# Extracting specific lines and export to the another txt file

Tags: powershell

I want to extract specific lines inside flat file and then export to the another txt file.

Lastly ,  I want to add information message via write-host.

```
done. 2 Records have been extracted in "C:\tmp\output.txt"
```

My input file:

```
MyComputer1234.child1 [AGE:3606209] 1200 A 172.2.3.4

MyComputer5678 [AGE:1782367] 1200 A 172.5.6.7

MyComputer90AB.child2 [AGE:2457912] 1200 A 172.9.0.1

MyComputerCDEF.child2 [AGE:1982627] 1200 A 172.10.11.12
```

My output  :

```
MyComputer90AB.child2 [AGE:2457912] 1200 A 172.9.0.1
MyComputerCDEF.child2 [AGE:1982627] 1200 A 172.10.11.12
```

script :

```
get-content $inputfile -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach { $_ -match "child2" }
```

My desired output:

```
MyComputer90AB [AGE:2457912] 1200 A 172.9.0.1

MyComputerCDEF [AGE:1982627] 1200 A 172.10.11.12
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't done anything to remove that portion of the string that you matched. This is easily accomplished with regular expressions.

```
Get-Content $inputfile |
 ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match "child2"){
        $_ -replace '\.child2'
    }
 }
```

Since the period (`.`) has a special meaning in regex you have to escape it with the backslash. I'd also recommend using a `switch` statement to read and parse the file.

```
switch -Regex -File $inputfile {
    'child2' {$_ -replace '\.child2'}
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on YOUR input file example.

```
$inputfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
MyComputer1234.child1 [AGE:3606209] 1200 A 172.2.3.4

MyComputer5678 [AGE:1782367] 1200 A 172.5.6.7

MyComputer90AB.child2 [AGE:2457912] 1200 A 172.9.0.1

MyComputerCDEF.child2 [AGE:1982627] 1200 A 172.10.11.12
'@ | Set-Content $inputfile
```

My first proposed solution

```
Get-Content $inputfile |
    ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match "child2"){
        $_ -replace '\.child2'
    }
}
```

The output

```
MyComputer90AB [AGE:2457912] 1200 A 172.9.0.1
MyComputerCDEF [AGE:1982627] 1200 A 172.10.11.12
```

My second proposed solution

```
switch -Regex -File $inputfile {
    'child2' {$_ -replace '\.child2'}
}
```

The output

```
MyComputer90AB [AGE:2457912] 1200 A 172.9.0.1
MyComputerCDEF [AGE:1982627] 1200 A 172.10.11.12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$content=(Get-Content "path\to\flatfile" | Select-String '\.child2') -replace '\.child2'

if($content)
{
    "done. {0} Records have been extracted in `"C:\tmp\output.txt`"" -f $content.count
    $content >> "C:\tmp\output.txt"
}
```

Comment: thanks so , how can I use `variable` instead of `\.child2`  ? ........  `| Select-String '\.$($extractZoneName)') -replace '\.$($extractZoneName)'`   not working

Comment: Use double quotes instead. `"\.$extractZoneName") -replace "\.$extractZoneName"` @Arbelac